# Need to run Python 3.5

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.5

I've installed Python 3.5 for the Mac, it was installed in:

```
/Applications/Python 3.5
```

When I open Idle, the shell starts off saying:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)
```

I've created a script and I'm running it through the Python launcher. The script says:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

It returns:

```
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
```

In the Python launcher preferences there's an option for changing the path to the Python interpreter that I want to use.  Right now it's set to:

```
/usr/bin/pythonw
```

In /usr/bin, the only versions of python are 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7.  Where did my 3.5 go and how can I point my Python launcher to the proper place?

Comment: fixing issues with OS X launchers seems out of place on stackoverflow for me. maybe you should ask that question on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: why not use venv . It makes life lot easier

Comment: Create a symbolic link to python3.5 in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: I don't mind doing it from the command line, in fact I prefer to to it that way and not use the launcher. This isn't a launcher issue, it's a matter of getting Python to use the right version. I get the same problem when I run the script in the terminal.

I've created a soft link to python3.5 in my /usr/bin directory, but to no avail. 

venv looks interesting though, lemme look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PATH environment issue. If you want /Applications/Python 3.5 to launch in preference to any other version, you need to edit your shell profile to put /Applications before any other directory.

If this is a foreign concept, then you are better off removing Python 3.5 from your Applications folder and installing the Anaconda 3.x version (currently at 3.4.3, but don't let that worry you).

In **no** event, however, mess with the pythons in /usr/bin. You'll end up having to reinstall the OS in all likelihood.

If you look at the **man** page for *pythonw* you'll see that it can't be changed from 2.7 upward. The Anaconda executable by the same name simply calls the most current Anaconda version.

With your current setup, you could work around the issues with appropriate shell aliases, but I'm guessing that if these were familiar tools you already would have answered your own question. Take a look at Anaconda.com; it's free, well supported and you won't have to worry about these sorts of questions. It will also make installing packages much easier.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried the path thing by editing my .bash_profile file. 
When I "echo $PATH" I get this:
/Applications:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Running my script (from the command line this time, instead of the launcher thing) it still returns 2.7.5. I'd like to get the path sorted out since I feel like I'm almost there and just missing something small.

Comment: Checking the pkg install instructions, invoke with python3: "ython 3 and Python 2 Co-existence

Python.org Python 3.5 and 2.7.x versions can both be installed on your system and will not conflict. Command names for Python 3 contain a 3 in them, python3 (or python3.5), idle3 (or idle3.5), pip3 (or pip3.5), etc.  Python 2.7 command names contain a 2 or no digit: python2 (or python2.7 or python), idle2 (or idle2.7 or idle), etc."

Comment: Okay, got the path issue fixed using setx PATH. Thanks everyone!